# EF Core building SQL query takes long time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using .Net Core 5 and EF Core.

I have a function that builds a dynamic SQL query based on parameters passed in:

```
 public IQueryable < game > GetTopGamesByCategory(GameCategories category,
     string name, int offset = 0, int range = 10) {

  var gameQueryable = context.games
    .Include(g => g.gamescreenshots)
    .Include(g => g.GameTranslates)
    .Include(e => e.apps)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.master__apptype)
    .Include(e => e.apps)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.app_areas)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.master__area)
    .Where(t => t.categoryid == category &&
      t.isactive && !t.deleted.HasValue);

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    gameQueryable = gameQueryable
    .Where(g => g.title.Contains(name));

  return gameQueryable
    //.OrderByDescending(t => t.gametags
    //    .Sum(tag => tag.tag.popularity))
    //.ThenByDescending(t => t.created)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.priority)
    .ThenBy(t => t.iscomingsoon)
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.created)
    .Skip(offset * range)
    .Take(range);
}
```

This function just builds the query, doesn't actually execute it. From our performance insights, we found that this function is taking the majority of the time.

The next function that executes the query only takes a fraction of the time.

As far as I understand, this function should only be building the SQL query, and does not hit the database at all.

What could be taking so long to build the query? And how to optimize it?

Comment: Majority of time for one request or something? Could you be more specific on how you analyzed insights, what are the numbers? Say for example if this method gets executed 1000 times - then in summary the time of execution will be big obviously, but it doesn't mean that method itself is slow

Comment: This is just for one particular request. Usually this whole request takes under 100ms to execute. This one request had the majority of time spent on this function. Taking about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I don‘t believe that this function takes so much time. Use performance analyzers. Anyway try to replace this query with [Compiled Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities)

Comment: If this is the very first query, then it includes `DbContext` model and internal service provider building, which sometimes could be significant. Add `_ = context.Model;` at the beginning and see which of the two (this and `var gameQueryable = ...`) calls takes the most time.

Comment: @IvanStoev, nice catch, really forgot that EF has to build metadata for everything and they have introduced in EF Core 6 [Compiled Models](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-6-0-preview-5-compiled-models/)

Comment: Even then, the initial DbContext initialization occurs when the first query is executed, not during building a query expression.  OP, have you confirmed this behaviour with a debugger stepping into this method? Also ensuring the call to execute the query is awaited if using an `async` method like `ToListAsync`? What kinds of actual times are we talking about? All of these `Include` properties are vanilla navigation properties/collections? (Nothing wonky like going back to the DbContext..)

Comment: @StevePy *"Even then, the initial DbContext initialization occurs when the first query is executed, not during building a query expression."* That's not true. It really happens when you build a query referencing some definition ( `DbSet` ) from the context. You can easily verify that by putting breakpoint in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @StevePy `Include` are normal navigation properties. Hmm.. in the execution step of this query, I'm not using `ToListAsync`. I will try that to see if it solves this

Comment: I only mention that async & await since you wrote that the execution was faster than composing the query to ensure if it was an *Async method that it was awaited. @Ivan, I'll definitely double-check that behaviour when that warm-up occurs, but that would explain a first-pass cost in the OP's case.